# Typing something into the custom edit rejection reason box should select the corresponding radio button

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, suggested-edits

When I'm typing in a custom rejection reason into an edit I'm already a little bit frustrated that I have to break my normal clicking pattern to try to help empty the suggested edit queue as quickly as possible. It doesn't help that I have to make an extra click before I can press the reject button.

Notice how there is text in the textbox, and the textbox has focus, but the radio button by `custom` is still unmarked.

[image]

My feature request: either when I put focus on the textarea or when I start typing into the textarea, automatically check the radio button.

Comment: As far as I remember, the textbox should be disabled until you tick that radio button, so it sounds more like a bug.

Comment: This would also be a nice thing to have on the flag rejection thingie for mods.

Comment: I've also noticed that it doesn't automatically check the box (I think that's what it used to do). I haven't worried about it because it still uses my custom reason whether I select that box or not.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, at least on the current stable build of Chrome. Is it just missing a `[status-completed]` tag, or do you still notice this behavior?